# How can I select tags for autocomplete box?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

Here is my table structure:

```
// tags
+----+------------+----------------------------------+----------+----------+------------+
| id |    name    |            description           | related  | used_num | date_time  |
+----+------------+----------------------------------+----------+----------+------------+
| 1  | PHP        | some explanations for PHP        | 1        | 4234     | 1475028896 |
| 2  | SQL        | some explanations for SQL        | 2        | 734      | 1475048601 |
| 3  | jQuery     | some explanations for jQuery     | 3        | 434      | 1475068321 | 
| 4  | MySQL      | some explanations for MySQL      | 2        | 657      | 1475068332 |
| 5  | JavaScript | some explanations for JavaScript | 3        | 3325     | 1475071430 |
| 6  | HTML       | some explanations for HTML       | 6        | 2133     | 1475077842 |
| 7  | postgresql | some explanations for postgresql | 2        | 43       | 1475077851 |
| 8  | script     | some explanations for script     | 8        | 3        | 1475077935 |
+----+------------+----------------------------------+----------+----------+------------+
```

Now I need to select tags base on a part of their names, Also I need to select all related tags.

---

**For examples:**

String: `scr`. expected output:

```
+----+------------+----------------------------------+----------+----------+------------+
| 3  | jQuery     | some explanations for jQuery     | 3        | 434      | 1475068321 | 
| 5  | JavaScript | some explanations for JavaScript | 3        | 3325     | 1475071430 |
| 8  | script     | some explanations for script     | 8        | 3        | 1475077935 |
+----+------------+----------------------------------+----------+----------+------------+
-- Noted that "jQuery" tag is selected because of its relation with "JavaScript" tag
```

String: `ph`. expected output:

```
+----+------------+----------------------------------+----------+----------+------------+
| 1  | PHP        | some explanations for PHP        | 1        | 4234     | 1475028896 |
+----+------------+----------------------------------+----------+----------+------------+
```

String: `ys`. expected output:

```
+----+------------+----------------------------------+----------+----------+------------+
| 2  | SQL        | some explanations for SQL        | 2        | 734      | 1475048601 |
| 4  | MySQL      | some explanations for MySQL      | 2        | 657      | 1475068332 |
| 7  | postgresql | some explanations for postgresql | 2        | 43       | 1475077851 |
+----+------------+----------------------------------+----------+----------+------------+
-- Noted that both "SQL" and "postgresql" are selected because of their relation with "MySQL" tag
```

---

How can I do that?

Actually I can do that like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tags WHERE name LIKE %:str%
```

But my query doesn't support `related` column.

Comment: @Drew yeah I know, this isn't your recommended database design.

Answer (score 1):

Join the table on itself and look for rows with the occurrence in either of the two name columns. This way, you can search the name of the related elements as well.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tags t1
LEFT JOIN tags t2 ON t1.id = t2.related
WHERE t1.name LIKE %:str% OR t2.name LIKE %:str%;
```

Answer (score 1):

One option here is to self join the `tags` table and then group concatenate the related tags based on an input tag.  The query below will output a CSV list of tags related to a given input.  For example, if `:str` were `'MySQL'` then the output would be `'MySQL,postgresql,SQL'`.  If you are using a language like PHP or Java it should be easy enough to explode that CSV list and get those suggestions into the drop down for autocompletion.

```
SELECT t1.name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(t2.name)
FROM tags t1
INNER JOIN tags t2
    ON t1.id = t2.related
WHERE t1.name LIKE '%:str%'     -- e.g. MySQL
GROUP BY t1.name
```

You could also do a self join and return one record for each suggested tag:

```
SELECT t2.name
FROM tags t1
INNER JOIN tags t2
    ON t1.id = t2.related
WHERE t1.name LIKE '%:str%'     -- e.g. MySQL
```

Comment: Why your e.g. is a full-tag-name? Would it also work for not-full-tag-names? Like `mys` or `ysql` or `ys` ?

Comment: Just one thing, why didn't you select `description` and `used_num` columns? I'm trying to make some thing like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/vBjlH.png

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
SELECT * FROM tags a WHERE name LIKE %:str% or exist (SELECT id FROM tags b WHERE b.name LIKE %:str%  and b.id=a.related)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since autocomplete must be fast, you cannot afford to be looking in more than one place for the answer.

Build (and maintain) a special table for autocomplete; it will have one text (or varchar) column with all possible keywords for a given item, plus another column(s) with the info about what it refers to.

Comment: Sounds nice, upvote .. but really vague .. can you please explain me some more explanations? or a table structure and a query?